# sort an array contain number and letter

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

when sort an array with letter and number, like below:
    $a = array(0, 1, 'a', 'A');
    sort($a);
    print_r($a);

the result confuse me like that:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => 0 [2] => A [3] => 1 )
```

why the '0' between in 'a' and 'A'?

Comment: php.net - Warning: Be careful when sorting arrays with mixed types values because sort() can produce unpredictable results.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski, then how do i sort an array like that in ASCII? i  except it would be an result like : array(0,1,a,A)...

Comment: Specify the second parameter to SORT_NUMERIC. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php. And capital letters come before lowercase in ASCII.

Comment: Depending on the order that you're actually wanting, you might prefer to use the `SORT_NATURAL` flag as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>When you do that, the numbers are converted to a string. Number character ASCII values come between the two cases.</strike>

The strings are converted to numbers. It takes any number characters at the beginning and drops everything else to compare, unless it finds '.','E', or 'e', which can be used for floating-point conversion. If it finds no numeric characters, it evaluates to zero.

Comment: and consider specifying `SORT_NATURAL` or `SORT_STRING`